# Django Extra Views - Delete "InlineFormset" if condition is met on Update

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, inline-formset

So I'm using Django Extra Views to set up an orderform which includes both bookings and payments. Employees can create an Order which includes one or several Bookings and optionally include several Payments.

Since the payments are optional, the total amount will be checked on saving the form. If the total payment > 0, the payment_formset is saved.

The problem now is, what if an employee makes a mistake and wants to remove a payment? I do need a "min_num: 1" on the PaymentInlineForm on creating the form but I want to check if the total_payment == 0, and if it does, remove the associated payment records. I tried using payment_formset.delete() but it gives me the error;

> 'PaymentFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'delete'

## views.py - Inlines

```
# Setting up the order form with inlines
class BookingInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    prefix = 'booking_formset'
    factory_kwargs = {
        'extra': 0,
        'min_num': 1,
        'validate_min': True,
        'can_delete': True
    }

class PaymentInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Payment
    form_class = PaymentForm
    prefix = 'payment_formset'
    factory_kwargs = {
        'extra': 0,
        'min_num': 1,
        'validate_min': False,
        'can_delete': True
    }
```

## views.py - OrderUpdateView

```
class OrderUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, NamedFormsetsMixin, UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    inlines = [BookingInline, PaymentInline]
    inlines_names = ['booking_formset', 'payment_formset']
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'orders/order_update_form.html'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('order_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
    booking_formset = inlines[0]
    payment_formset = inlines[1]

    """
    If the form and formsets are valid, save the associated models.
    """
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.updated_by = self.request.user
    # Check if coupon is applied and copy the discount to the order table
    coupon = form.cleaned_data['coupon']
    if coupon:
        self.object.coupon_used = self.object.coupon.code
        self.object.coupon_discount = self.object.coupon.discount
    form.save(commit=True)
    booking_formset.save()

    payments = payment_formset.save(commit=False)
    total_payment = sum(payment.amount for payment in payments)
    if total_payment > 0:
        payment_formset.save()
    elif total_payment == 0:
        payment_formset.delete()


    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

## Problem

```
if total_payment > 0:
    payment_formset.save()
elif total_payment == 0:
    payment_formset.delete()
```

If the total of all payments equals 0, the associated payment records should be deleted. Currently it keeps the old records and does not remove them from the database.

Any help would be appreciated, or maybe there's a different approach to tackle this?

With best regards,

Kevin

## Edit

From the documentation; If you call formset.save(commit=False), objects will not be deleted automatically. You’ll need to call delete() on each of the formset.deleted_objects to actually delete them:

```
payments = payment_formset.save(commit=False)
total_payment = sum(payment.amount for payment in payments)
if total_payment > 0:
    payment_formset.save()
elif total_payment == 0:
    for payment in payment_formset.deleted_objects:
        payment.delete()
```

So I should mark all payments to be deleted if the total_payment equals zero...

Comment: Simple `del payment_formset` is not working?

Comment: No it does not, maybe I should mark all payments to be deleted if the total sum equals zero. But I'm not sure yet...